# using dynamically created labels c#

Tags: c#

So I have

```
TableLayoutPanel table = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
public int d;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    d = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    table.ColumnCount = d;
    table.RowCount = d;
    this.Controls.Add(table);
    int k = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
        {
            Label lab = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            lab.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            lab.Text = (k).ToString();
            lab.TabIndex = k++;
            lab.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            table.Controls.Add(lab, j, i);
        }
    table.Show();
}
```

That is one Button Click method. 
I have Button2 Click method and I want to change lab.TabIndex or/and lab.Text.
How can I do that?

And second question:
how can i do something on Click one of that labels? Let's say that i want to change a color one of the labels i click...how can I do that?

I'm a beginner so...have mercy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a array of labels (global variable, like you did with `table`):

```
Label[] labels;
```

in `button1_Click`, add the line of code:

```
labels = new Label[d*d]; // array of d*d labels
```

inside the loop, define the specific label, like:

```
labels[i*d+j] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
```

So your loop will look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
   for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
   {
      labels[i*d+j] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
      labels[i*d+j].Size = new Size(50, 50);
      labels[i*d+j].Text = (k).ToString();
      labels[i*d+j].TabIndex = k++;
      labels[i*d+j].TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
      table.Controls.Add(labels[i*d+j], j, i);
   }
```

you can access them from other buttons also in the same way (`labels[n]`)